# How are astronaut nametags printed when their family name is first?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, spacesuits, astronaut-lifestyle, language

It is traditional in English and Russian to print a person's given name before their family name.  However, there are some languages where that order is reversed.

When flying on an American or Russian spacecraft (or the ISS), **how is a person's name printed on their nametag if they come from a culture which prints the family name first?**

Inspired by [this excellent question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48060/26446).

[image: Chris Hadfield's bilingual name tag on a space suit]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They use the same given-name-initial followed by full-family-name format, as seen in this picture of JAXA astronaut [Norishige Kanai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norishige_Kanai) (Kanai is his family name):

[image]

Comment: Even in their JAXA coveralls it's this way. I have an old picture of Naoko Sumino (the maiden name of Naoko Yamazaki) in her JAXA coverall and it's like this.

Comment: @OrganicMarble because of the inherent implications of "maiden", these days [née is often used instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_name#Maiden_and_married_names) though it still caries a gender reference, e.g. [Sunita Lyn Williams (**née** Pandya; born September 19, 1965) is an American astronaut and United States Navy officer...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunita_Williams)

Comment: @uhoh I don't care about that.

Comment: @OrganicMarble okay, may do. SE is a public forum, posts and comments are read by many people. That will be informative to many and may resonate especially with  those *who have had to deal with the term "maiden name" personally*.

Comment: Japanese names are given name-family name. How do, say, Korean astronauts do it?

Comment: @AntonHengst Korean names are usually family name-given name. But in space, Korea's only cosmonaut to date, [Yi So-yeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yi_So-yeon), still had the given name-family name order of name tags: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Yi%2BMalenchenko%2BWhitson_at_ISS_08Apr17_%28NASA-ISS016-E-036365%29.jpg

Comment: @uhoh "née" isn't used _instead of_ "maiden name". The former is an adjective and the latter is a noun. "Birth name" is a gender-neutral or masculine alternative used instead of "maiden name". But "maiden name" is still the correct term and hasn't fallen out of use (at least in the British English-speaking world that I'm aware of).

Comment: @AaronF I did not say "in place of". I have not seen them used together. Instead, they seem to be exclusive of each otherr; if one is used, the other isn't, so I think that my use of *instead of* is correct and proper as far as it goes, unless you can show me a case where they really are used together! However thanks for the background and for mentioning "birth name".

Answer (score 8):

Different default orderings of names had already become an issue during the [interkosmos programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interkosmos).

Printing the family name last on the tags has stuck for consistency. Below is Vietnamese cosmonaut [Phạm Tuân](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ph%E1%BA%A1m_Tu%C3%A2n), where "Phạm" is the family name.

Despite shortening names to their given name being the custom in Vietnam ([due to low family name entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_common_surnames_in_Asia#Vietnam)), the tag still reads "PHAM" + "ФАМ"

[image: Soyuz 37 crew]