# What mission is this Chris Hadfield photo associated with and what is the location? And what is that thing?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, identify-this-object, spacesuits, insignia, mission-patch

Many, many astronauts have gone on to be wonderful orators, educators, advocates for science, education and positive thinking, <s>Major Tom</s> Colonel (ret) and (fmr) ISS Commander Chris Hadfield is just one of them. I linked to a video in which he appears in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48054/12102) at `02:41` because of his plain-spoken clarity.

But go back to `02:26` and there's a file photo of Hadfield in a space suit. There's a mission patch and several other visual clues in the photo.

**Question:** What mission is this photo of Chris Hadfield associated with and what is the location of the photo? What is that ~30 cm mirror-like thing to their right (our left)?

[image: Chris Hadfield in a suit]

Comment: He's sitting in a chair on Earth being interviewed https://globalnews.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chris-hadfield-getty-e1367853848847.jpg?quality=85&strip=all You can see the foam mike cover here. Interesting logo on the frying pan thing, can't seem to turn it up.  Looks old school Russian.

Comment: I'm glad this got bumped, I had meant to look into this and forgotten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What mission is this photo of Chris Hadfield associated with

Expedition 34/35, specifically the Soyuz TMA-07M launch crew.

> and what is the location of the photo?

The Gagarin Cosmonaut Training Center in Star City, Russia

> What is that ~30 cm mirror-like thing to their right (our left)?

It's a frame for the insignia of the training center.

Here's a picture of the full crew in front of the Soyuz simulator with the logo at left and right.

[image]

> Caption: Space Station crew. Three members of the Soyuz TMA-07M crew that formed part of the Expedition 34/35 team on the International Space Station. Left to right are: Chris Hadfield (Canada, b.1959); Roman Romanenko (Russia, b.1971) and Thomas Marshburn (USA, b.1960). TMA-07M was launched on 19 December 2012. These three returned to Earth on 13 May 2013. Photographed during training at the Gagarin Cosmonaut Training Centre at Star City near Moscow, Russia.

Source: [SciencePhoto](https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/552350/view/crew-of-soyuz-tma-07m-in-training)

This [article](http://avianik.com/en/news/44/) confirms the id of the logo, although it appears to vary slightly in all three depictions, even the ones to the left and right of the simulator.

[image]

Here's another picture of the simulator from [here](http://starcity-tours.com/dayphoto/gagarin-cosmonaut-training-centre-tour-soyuz-tma-spacecraft-simulator/).

[image]

Comment: thorough answer, snazzy logo!

Answer (score 4):

I don't have the exact context but he appears to be wearing the Sokol spacesuit. It is used when launching to or returning from space with the Russian Soyuz spacecraft. He only did his last mission (Expedition 35) with the Soyuz. This being the one where he was the ISS Commander.